# How do I simultaneously view multiple diffs with Magit?

Tags: magit

How can I simultaneously view multiple diffs with Magit? I want to view A..B in one window, and A..C in another window (B and C are diverged branches).

I can run `magit-diff-dwim` on A..B to view the first diff, but when I run it the second time on A..C, it appears to reuse the same buffer, replacing the A..B diff with A..C. I want to see A..B and A..C side by side to help resolve a merge conflict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current Magit (v2.3.0), you can make a buffer stick around by calling `magit-toggle-buffer-lock`.  In earlier versions, `magit-rename-buffer` served a similar purpose.

Comment: Upgrading Magit and using `magit-toggle-buffer-lock` did the trick. Thanks for the quick response.